# cakePHP: Look for a row inside database by using other fields other than primary key?

Tags: cakephp, controller

I'm going to check if a row exists in my DB which one of its field matches a custom value.
e.g. consider table licences which contains fields: (id,serial,validity).
I'm going to check two conditions in my controller:

1. licence with serial 'xyz' is presents in db
2. licence with serial 'xyz' have validity field value 'valid'

How should i complete $option for this code:

```
public function validity($serial = null) {
    $this->autoRender = false; // We don't render a view in this example
    $options = ?????;
    $license = $this->License->find('first', $options);
    if ($license){
        // it is valid and present
        $data = array('validity' => 'valid');
    );
    }else{
        //not present actions
        $data = array('validity' => 'invalid');
    }

    $this->response->body(json_encode($data));
}
```

Comment: You really should check the docs first: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options argument has a lot of parameters you can use like conditions, order and fields. In your case you need conditions

```
$options=array('conditions'=>array('License.serial'=>'xyz', 'License.validity'='valid'));
```

(by default it is AND between conditions)

Comment: Is it possible to use a syntax which avoids typo errors? this way i mean using `'License.serial'` is prone to typo errors and model will not check them.

Comment: Typo is a disadvantage to this method i agree but it helps to differentiate models because if you have associations then your conditions are cross-model (joins)